# How to call hash values outside class from defined hash map inside class methods?

Tags: ruby

Read a csv format file and construct a new class with the name of the file dynamically. So if the csv is persons.csv, the ruby class should be person, if it's places.csv, the ruby class should be places 
Also create methods for reading and displaying each value in "csv" file and values in first row of csv file will act as name of the function. 
Construct an array of objects and associate each object with the row of a csv file. For example the content of the csv file could be

```
name,age,city 
abd,45,TUY 
kjh,65,HJK
```

Previous code :

```
require 'csv'

class Feed
  def initialize(source_name, column_names = [])
    if column_names.empty?
      column_names = CSV.open(source_name, 'r', &:first)
    end
    columns = column_names.reduce({}) { |columns, col_name| columns[col_name] = []; columns }

    define_singleton_method(:columns) { column_names }

    column_names.each do |col_name|
      define_singleton_method(col_name.to_sym) { columns[col_name] }
    end

    CSV.foreach(source_name, headers: true) do |row|
      column_names.each do |col_name|
        columns[col_name] << row[col_name]
      end
    end
  end
end

feed = Feed.new('input.csv')
puts feed.columns #["name", "age", "city"]
puts feed.name # ["abd", "kjh"]
puts feed.age # ["45", "65"]
puts feed.city # ["TUY", "HJK"]
```

I am trying to refine this solution using class methods and split code into smaller methods. Calling values outside the class using key names but facing errors like  "undefined method `age' for Feed:Class". Is that a way I can access values outside the class ?
My solution looks like -

```
require 'csv'
class Feed
  attr_accessor :column_names
  def self.col_name(source_name, column_names = [])
    if column_names.empty?
      @column_names = CSV.open(source_name, :headers => true)
    end
    columns = @column_names.reduce({}) { |columns, col_name| columns[col_name] = []; columns }
  end

  def self.get_rows(source_name)
    col_name(source_name, column_names = [])
    define_singleton_method(:columns) { column_names }

    column_names.each do |col_name|
      define_singleton_method(col_name.to_sym) { columns[col_name] }
    end

    CSV.foreach(source_name, headers: true) do |row|
      @column_names.each do |col_name|
        columns[col_name] << row[col_name]
      end
    end
  end
end

obj = Feed.new
Feed.get_rows('Input.csv')
puts obj.class.columns
puts obj.class.name
puts obj.class.age
puts obj.class.city
```

Expected Result -

```
input = Input.new
p input.name  # ["abd", "kjh"]
p input.age # ["45", "65"]
input.name ='XYZ' # Value must be appended to array
input.age = 25
p input.name # ["abd", "kjh", "XYZ"]
p input.age # ["45", "65", "25"]
```

Comment: You need to remove spaces at the ends of the lines `"name,age,city "` and `"abd,45,TUY "`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's create the CSV file.

```
str =<<END
name,age,city
abd,45,TUY
kjh,65,HJK
END
```

```
FName = 'temp/persons.csv'

File.write(FName, str)
  #=> 36
```

Now let's create a class:

```
klass = Class.new
  #=> #<Class:0x000057d0519de8a0>
```

and name it:

```
class_name = File.basename(FName, ".csv").capitalize
  #=> "Persons"
Object.const_set(class_name, klass)
  #=> Persons
Persons.class
  #=> Class
```

See [File::basename](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/File.html#method-c-basename), [String#capitalize](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-capitalize) and [Module#const_set](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-const_set).

Next read the CSV file with headers into a `CSV::Table` object:

```
require 'csv'

csv = CSV.read(FName, headers: true)
  #=> #<CSV::Table mode:col_or_row row_count:3> 
csv.class
  #=> CSV::Table
```

See [CSV#read](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-read). We may now create the methods `name`, `age` and `city`.

```
 csv.headers.each { |header| klass.define_method(header) { csv[header] } }
```

See [CSV#headers](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-i-headers), [Module::define_method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html) and [CSV::Row#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.3/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV/Row.html#method-i-5B-5D).

We can now confirm they work as intended:

```
k = klass.new
k.name
  #=> ["abd", "kjh"] 
k.age
  #=> ["45", "65"] 
k.city
  #=> ["TUY", "HJK"]
```

or

```
p = Persons.new
  #=> #<Persons:0x0000598dc6b01640> 
p.name
  #=> ["abd", "kjh"]
```

and so on.